# Loop only works once

Tags: python

.
dd language identifier to highlight code

```py
def function(foo):
    print(foo)
```

► put returns between paragraphs

► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end

► *italic* or **bold**

► indent code by 4 spaces

► backtick escapes `like _so_`

► quote by placing > at start of line

Comment: Did you try printing `len(files)` before going into that `for` loop?

Comment: @Rafalon it says 2

Comment: Is there any chance that in the "*rest of the code inside this branch*" you do anything that can change the content of `files`? Just print `len(files)` *inside* the loop, before `print s`.

Comment: It is always better to iterate through the list directly: `for file in files: ...`

Comment: Please post a code that can reproduce the issue. We cannot figure it out without the problematic part. More likely the issue is held in `rest of the code`. There is probably a short way to reproduce it without pasting the whole code. You can check how to write a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `for` is causing you trouble (with the `len` and the `range`), why not simply do:

```
for file in files:
    print file
```

Much simpler, much cleaner, and it may give you a better indication as to what exactly is wrong.

I suspect that you are altering the `s` variable (or potentially the `files` variable) later on in your code. Also, may I suggest using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)?

Comment: I don't think he's altering `s` as it prints `1` which is what it should be (`0` then `1`). Instead I think he's altering `files`.

Comment: Nope. `file` is (I believe) a file name. You can open the file, alter it, delete it, or anything. The `file` variable will still contain the file name. Editing the `files` array is a completely different story, and this should not be necessary.

Comment: I never said it was necessary, I said I suspected OP did it (maybe not on purpose). Either clearing it or removing an element from it but still it appears that before the loop it contains 2 elements and on second iteration it contains less than 2 elements

Comment: Very kind, but usually poor questions lead to poor answers. I'd wait for the OP to work it out a little more (like being able to reproduce) before suggesting debugging tips.

Comment: I just did that, it's much simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I removed the global assignment (besides making it python 3) and tested with a shorter test command `python script.py -f traj1.gro,traj2.gro -i 1 -s 30`:

```
import sys
files = []
#global files

for i in sys.argv[1:]:
    if i == '-f':
        file = sys.argv[sys.argv.index('-f')+1] #input filenames after -f
        for j in file.split(','):
            files.append(j)

for s in range(len(files)):
    file = ''
    print(s)
    print(files[s])
    file = files[s]
```

It spitted out:

```
0
traj1.gro
1
traj2.gro
```

I would recommend not using system names like file and files for variables

Comment: I just checked everything, and realized that I globalized "files". There were some identical "files" words inside the big block of code, which I changed to "filess" or something. Thanks!